# How to Implement a method that finds the largest value, given two arrays(String[], Float[])

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, foreach

I have two arrays both with 12 elements each. One is a string array with 4 different colors, and the rest being duplicate colors. The second array is a float array with 12 distinct values.

```
string[] fishColor = new string[] {"blue", "red", "green", "pink", "blue", "pink", "blue", "red", "green", "blue", "red", "green"};

float[] fishLength = new float[12] { 8.2f, 17.1f, 23.2f, 2.3f, 5.5f, 7.83f, 9.6f, 10.7f, 12.3f, 4.2f, 8.71f, 9.17f };
```

The goal is to create a method that will find the largest float value for a given color. For example, there are a total of 4 strings with the value of "blue", and each of these has a corresponding float value:

fishColor[0] = "Blue" would be paired with fishLength[0] = 8.2 
fishColor[4] = "Blue" would be paired with fishLength[4] = 5.5

etc...

The method must be able to find the largest amongst the duplicates.

For context, I have a menu that lists the four different colors in the string array. The only user input in this program would be the menu option the user picks, so one of the colors.

```
 bool fin = false;

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nWelcome to BigBlueFish!\r\n\r\nPlease select a fish color below...");

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n[1] Blue");

            Console.WriteLine("\r\n[2] Red");

            Console.WriteLine("\r\n[3] Green");

            Console.WriteLine("\r\n[4] Pink");

            Console.WriteLine("\r\n[0] Exit to main menu");

            string strSelect = Console.ReadLine();

            int numSelect;

            try
            {
                numSelect = int.Parse(strSelect);

            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nPlease select a menu option!");
                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nYou have selected {0}", numSelect);

            switch (numSelect)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nTill next time!");
                    fin = true;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    var mdata1 = FindBiggestFish(fishColor, fishLength);
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nWell now seems like you found the biggest blue fish is {0}in", mdata1);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    var mdata2 = FindBiggestFish(fishColor, fishLength);
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nWell now seems like you found the biggest red fish is {0}in", mdata2);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    var mdata3 = FindBiggestFish(fishColor, fishLength);
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nWell now seems like you found the biggest green fish is {0}in", mdata3);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    var mdata4 = FindBiggestFish(fishColor, fishLength);
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nWell now seems like you found the biggest pink fish is {0}in", mdata4);
                    break;

            }

        } while (!fin);


    }

    public static float FindBiggestFish(string[] col, float[] len)
    {
       float bgstCol = 0;

        var colAndLen = col.Zip(len, (c, l) => new { color = c, length = l });

        foreach(var cl in colAndLen)
        {
            if (cl.color.Distinct().Count() != cl.color.Count())
            {
                 rptCol = cl.color;
                 bgstCol = cl.length;
            }
        }

        return bgstCol;

    }
```

The user selects an option from the menu and the method is applied the result should look like this:

Selection was 1

Whoa, looks like the biggest blue fish is 9.6 inches

The method would see that there are 4 instances of "blue" fish and locate that the largest one of the 4 is 9.6.

All of that to ask, how would I correctly implement this as a method? I ended up trying to go the LINQ route so as to pair the two arrays together and iterate through them with a foreach, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing. Any insight on how to implement this would be much appreciated. If ya couldn't tell already I'm newer to programming so bear with me, you have my thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Zip` in order to create color / length pairs

```
      var result = fishColor
          .Zip(fishLength, (c, l) => new {c, l})
          .Where(item => item.c == givenColor)
          .Max(item => item.l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all entries and store the maximum per color:

```cs
var max_values = new Dictionary<string,double>();
for( int i=0; i<fishColor.Length; i++)
{
  var clr = fishColor[i];
  var len = fishLength[i];
  if (! max_values.ContainsKey( clr ) )
  {
    max_values.Add( clr , len );
    continue;
  }
  if (max_values[ clr ] < len )
    max_values[ clr ] = len;
}
```

Comment: Minor points; 1) these are arrays, so Length should be used/there is no Count property, only Count() method from LINQ extensions (but Length would be preferable), 2) with dictionary ContainsKey() should be used to see if the dict knows of the color string; Contains is LINQ and nerds a KeyValuePair and 3) having a temp var for color[i] and length[i] might make things a bit more readable

Answer (score 0):

You can populate Dictionary with the required pair of values using the below code.

```
        string[] fishColor = new string[] { "blue", "red", "green", "pink", "blue", "pink", "blue", "red", "green", "blue", "red", "green" };
        float[] fishLength = new float[12] { 8.2f, 17.1f, 23.2f, 2.3f, 5.5f, 7.83f, 9.6f, 10.7f, 12.3f, 4.2f, 8.71f, 9.17f };

        var dictFish = new Dictionary<string, float>();
        int index = 0;
        fishColor.ToList().ForEach(s =>
        {
            if (!dictFish.ContainsKey(s))
                dictFish.Add(s, fishLength[index]);
            else
            {
                if (dictFish[s] < fishLength[index])
                    dictFish[s] = fishLength[index];
            }
            index++;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

```
var lookupTable = fishColor.Zip(fishLength,(x,y)=>new {color=x,value=y}).ToLookup(x=>x.color);
var result = lookupTable[colorToSearch].Max(c=>c.value);
```

The `ToLookup` is immediately executed unlike GroupBy (which are differed executions). So if you intended to use the same collection for lookup for highest value of different color multiple times, it might be better you do the `ToLookup` once, and then search against it.